# Linear transformation - rotating a vector and projecting onto the x2 axis?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

[Picture of the problem I'm trying to solve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoU8E.png)

I did my best to mathjax the question: 
Consider the linear transformation T:R2 to R2 that first rotates a vector with pi/4 radians clockwise and then projects onto the x2 axis

(a) Find $$
    T\begin{pmatrix}
    1  \\
    1  \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Hello! I am confused on how to solve this problem - specifically (a). If someone could teach me step by step how to solve (a) I would be very grateful! I want to try solving (b) and (c) by myself after I learn how to do (a).

---

What I have tried to do so far on (a) is first I did-
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
  \cos(\pi/4)&-\sin(\pi/4)\\
  \sin(\pi/4)&\cos(\pi/4)
\end{array}
\right] $$

solved that matrix and whatever matrix I got as an answer I multiplied it by the x2 matrix

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
  -1&0\\
  0&1
\end{array}
\right] $$

and whatever was the result of that I would multiply by matrix

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
  1\\
  1
\end{array}
\right] $$

and that was my result for (a) but i have no idea if what i just did is totally wrong or what steps I need to take to get to the right answer?

Thank you!

Comment: Please use mathjax to format your question (https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @Andrei done! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part (a), let's go over step by step. This will help for part (b) as well.

The vector $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ has a length of $\sqrt{2}$, rotated $\pi/4$ counterclockwise from $x_1$ axis. When you rotate it clockwise by $\pi/4$, it will just point along $x_1$. You can write this in a matrix form:
$$\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\pi/4)&\sin(\pi/4)\\ -\sin(\pi/4)&\cos(\pi/4)\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt 2/2+\sqrt 2/2\\-\sqrt2/2+\sqrt2/2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt2\\0\end{bmatrix}$$
The next step is to project this vector onto the $x_2$ axis. What that means is that the second component is unchanged, and the first component become $0$. Then the final answer for (a) is $$T\left(\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}\right)=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$
The projection matrix onto the $x_2$ axis can be written as $$\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$ since $$\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\x_2\end{bmatrix}$$  When we apply this to the $\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt2\\0\end{bmatrix}$ vector we obtain $\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}$.

To summarize, we applied first the rotation (we multiplied the vector on the right with the rotation matrix), then we projected onto $x_2$ (we multiplied on the right the previous result by the projection matrix). So we write $$T\left(\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}\right)=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\left(\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\pi/4)&\sin(\pi/4)\\ -\sin(\pi/4)&\cos(\pi/4)\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}\right)$$

Therefore $$T=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\pi/4)&\sin(\pi/4)\\ -\sin(\pi/4)&\cos(\pi/4)\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\-\sqrt2/2&\sqrt2/2\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped clear a lot of questions. If you don't mind me asking - Is the projection matrix for x2 always default? Meaning if I were to have another problem that needed to project onto x2 i can still use that same matrix? Also the person above you who answered (Siong) said to use -pi/4 since it is clockwise. Is this still valid?

Comment: Yes. Loot at your rotation matrix and at mine. They differ by the sign of the off-diagonal terms. Notice that a $\pi/4$ clockwise rotation is equal to a $-\pi/4$ counterclockwise rotation, and that $\sin(-\pi/4)=-\sin(\pi/4)$ while $\cos(-\pi/4)=\cos(\pi/4)$

Comment: That clears things up! Thank you so much for taking the time to write everything out step by step with explanations! I'm truly grateful.

Comment: @Andrei I don't really understand why on the last part you multiplied the projection matrix with the rotation matrix instead of the other way around, because the rotation is applied first. So why is that?

Comment: @JurriaanBuitenweg I have two operations: projection $P$ and rotation $R$ acting on the vector $X$. First I apply rotation, so I get $RX$, then I apply the projection $P(RX)$. Use associativity to write it as $(PR)X$, so $TX=(PR)X$ means $T=PR$. The operations applied first is at the right, then you go towards left.

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

- The rotation is clockwise, hence rather than using $\frac{\pi}4$, we want to use $-\frac{\pi}4$.
- Projection onto $x_2$ should be $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Does this mean my steps I am taking are correct? Also what would the projection for x1 be, and are these matrix always the same (meaning I should memorize them)?